# java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 403

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i tried to post values from android mobile to my web server. i am getting 403 error with java.io.exception.

this is my logcat messages

```
[CDS]connect[local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80] tm:90
04-30 12:57:07.388  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process gcm.androidexample.com.ravi :80
04-30 12:57:07.413  10416-10416/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/InputMethodManager﹕ onWindowFocus: null softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#1810100
04-30 12:57:07.413  10416-10416/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/InputMethodManager﹕ deactivate the inputconnection in ControlledInputConnectionWrapper.
04-30 12:57:07.413  10416-10416/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/InputMethodManager﹕ START INPUT: com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{41cd4600 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-480,800} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41cfca48 controlFlags=#104
04-30 12:57:07.416  10416-10416/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/InputMethodManager﹕ Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41cfd2d8 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #186}
04-30 12:57:07.513  10416-10416/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-30 12:57:07.696  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][/192.168.1.70:36222] connected
04-30 12:57:07.696  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:0
04-30 12:57:07.820  10416-10416/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Flushing caches (mode 0)
04-30 12:57:08.012  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/AndroidRuntime﹕ zoneinfo:Asia/Calcutta
04-30 12:57:08.014  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[36222]
04-30 12:57:08.015  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:36222]
04-30 12:57:08.015  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/GCM Android Example﹕ Failed to register on attempt 1:java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 403
04-30 12:57:08.015  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Sleeping for 2401 ms before retry
04-30 12:57:10.416  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Attempt #2 to register
04-30 12:57:10.418  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/GCM Android Example﹕ Posting 'email=fvgghhgv@hhngfg.hjh&regId=APA91bFKaVLGMwjZ-4DywjSCncNlokYu96l_4MyIFCt1cqCYEnDlCr-WMns4IuuEVAyCOl8XGKgOKptfbUxHgiDS_qy65C48uRPsl3NCZRuOhtswsEuJZLSq2x5w0i-znjhdqYFhDwSUJHrr8ye-2vgMP6duXCW9pw&name=gfgh' to 
04-30 12:57:10.418  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/URL﹕ > 
04-30 12:57:10.425  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/libc-netbsd﹕ getaddrinfo: local.test.com get result from proxy >>
04-30 12:57:10.426  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ propertyValue:true
04-30 12:57:10.426  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][1] connection local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80;LocalPort=34236(0)
04-30 12:57:10.427  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ /192.99.166.230:80] tm:90
04-30 12:57:10.427  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process gcm.androidexample.com.ravi :80
04-30 12:57:10.460  10416-10436/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52c45438) fps:0.33, dur:3015.55, max:3015.55, min:3015.55
04-30 12:57:10.733  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][/192.168.1.70:34236] connected
04-30 12:57:10.733  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:0
04-30 12:57:11.045  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[34236]
04-30 12:57:11.046  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:34236]
04-30 12:57:11.046  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/GCM Android Example﹕ Failed to register on attempt 2:java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 403
04-30 12:57:11.047  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android xample﹕ Sleeping for 4802 ms before retry
04-30 12:57:15.849  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Attempt #3 to register
04-30 12:57:15.873  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/GCM Android Example﹕ Posting 'email=fvgghhgv@hhngfg.hjh&regId=APA91bFKaVLGMwjZ-4DywjSCncNlokYu96l_4MyIFCt1cqCYEnDlCr-WMns4IuuEVAyCOl8XGKgOKptfbUxHgiDS_qy65C48uRPsl3NCZRuOhtswsEuJZLSq2x5w0i-znjhdqYFhDwSUJHrr8ye-2vgMP6duXCW9pw&name=gfgh' to 
04-30 12:57:15.885  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/URL﹕ > 
04-30 12:57:15.889  10416-10436/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52c45438) fps:0.18, dur:5428.43, max:5428.43, min:5428.43
04-30 12:57:15.889  10416-10436/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x52c45438, api:1, last queue time elapsed:5428.43
04-30 12:57:15.891  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/libc-netbsd﹕ getaddrinfo: local.test.com get result from proxy >>
04-30 12:57:15.891  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ propertyValue:true
04-30 12:57:15.892  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][2] connection local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80;LocalPort=44926(0)
04-30 12:57:15.892  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ 
04-30 12:57:15.893  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process gcm.androidexample.com.ravi :80
04-30 12:57:16.202  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][/192.168.1.70:44926] connected
04-30 12:57:16.202  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:0
04-30 12:57:16.503  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[44926]
04-30 12:57:16.504  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:44926]
04-30 12:57:16.504  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/GCM Android Example﹕ Failed to register on attempt 3:java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 403
04-30 12:57:16.505  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Sleeping for 9604 ms before retry
04-30 12:57:26.109  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Attempt #4 to register
04-30 12:57:26.140  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/GCM Android Example﹕ Posting 'email=fvgghhgv@hhngfg.hjh&regId=APA91bFKaVLGMwjZ-4DywjSCncNlokYu96l_4MyIFCt1cqCYEnDlCr-WMns4IuuEVAyCOl8XGKgOKptfbUxHgiDS_qy65C48uRPsl3NCZRuOhtswsEuJZLSq2x5w0i-znjhdqYFhDwSUJHrr8ye-2vgMP6duXCW9pw&name=gfgh' to 
04-30 12:57:26.145  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/URL﹕ > 
I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52c45438) fps:0.10, dur:10271.53, max:10271.53, min:10271.53
04-30 12:57:26.160  10416-10436/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x52c45438, api:1, last queue time elapsed:10271.53
04-30 12:57:26.162  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/libc-netbsd﹕ getaddrinfo: local.test.com get result from proxy >>
04-30 12:57:26.165  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ propertyValue:true
04-30 12:57:26.166  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ 
04-30 12:57:26.166  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80] tm:90
04-30 12:57:26.174  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process gcm.androidexample.com.ravi :80
04-30 12:57:26.492  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][/192.168.1.70:45892] connected
04-30 12:57:26.492  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:0
04-30 12:57:26.806  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[45892]
04-30 12:57:26.806  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:45892]
04-30 12:57:26.807  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/GCM Android Example﹕ Failed to register on attempt 4:java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 403
04-30 12:57:26.807  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Sleeping for 19208 ms before retry
04-30 12:57:46.015  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/GCM Android Example﹕ Attempt #5 to register
04-30 12:57:46.044  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi V/GCM Android Example﹕ Posting 'email=fvgghhgv@hhngfg.hjh&regId=APA91bFKaVLGMwjZ-4DywjSCncNlokYu96l_4MyIFCt1cqCYEnDlCr-WMns4IuuEVAyCOl8XGKgOKptfbUxHgiDS_qy65C48uRPsl3NCZRuOhtswsEuJZLSq2x5w0i-znjhdqYFhDwSUJHrr8ye-2vgMP6duXCW9pw&name=gfgh' to 
04-30 12:57:46.051  10416-10436/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x52c45438) fps:0.05, dur:19890.52, max:19890.52, min:19890.52
04-30 12:57:46.051  10416-10436/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/SurfaceTextureClient﹕ [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x52c45438, api:1, last queue time elapsed:19890.52
04-30 12:57:46.060  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/URL﹕ > http://local.test.com/gcmfile/register
04-30 12:57:46.065  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/libc-netbsd﹕ 
04-30 12:57:46.066  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ propertyValue:true
04-30 12:57:46.066  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][4] connection local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80;LocalPort=38220(0)
04-30 12:57:46.066  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80] tm:90
04-30 12:57:46.067  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process gcm.androidexample.com.ravi :80
04-30 12:57:46.390  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [socket][/192.168.1.70:38220] connected
04-30 12:57:46.393  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]rx timeout:0
04-30 12:57:46.701  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]close[38220]
04-30 12:57:46.702  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:38220]
04-30 12:57:46.702  10416-10434/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi E/GCM Android Example﹕ Failed to register on attempt 5:java.io.IOException: Post failed with error code 403
```

this is my code on register

```
package gcm.androidexample.com.ravi;

/**
 * Created by Thidiff on 4/24/2015.
 */

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;

import gcm.androidexample.com.gcm.R;

public class Controller extends Application{

    private  final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5;
    private  final int BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS = 2000;
    private  final Random random = new Random();


    // Register this account with the server.
    void register(final Context context, String name, String email, final String regId) {

        Log.i(Config.TAG, "registering device (regId = " + regId + ")");

        String serverUrl = Config.YOUR_SERVER_URL;

        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("regId", regId);
        params.put("name", name);
        params.put("email", email);

        long backoff = BACKOFF_MILLI_SECONDS + random.nextInt(1000);
        String res = "";
        // Once GCM returns a registration id, we need to register on our server
        // As the server might be down, we will retry it a couple
        // times.
        for (int i = 1; i <= MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++) {

            Log.d(Config.TAG, "Attempt #" + i + " to register");

            try {
                //Send Broadcast to Show message on screen
                displayMessageOnScreen(context, context.getString(
                        R.string.server_registering, i, MAX_ATTEMPTS));

                // Post registration values to web server
               post(serverUrl, params);


                GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);

                //Send Broadcast to Show message on screen
                String message = context.getString(R.string.server_registered);
                displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);

                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {

                // Here we are simplifying and retrying on any error; in a real
                // application, it should retry only on unrecoverable errors
                // (like HTTP error code 503).

                Log.e(Config.TAG, "Failed to register on attempt " + i + ":" + e);

                if (i == MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
                    break;
                }
                try {

                    Log.d(Config.TAG, "Sleeping for " + backoff + " ms before retry");
                    Thread.sleep(backoff);

                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    // Activity finished before we complete - exit.
                    Log.d(Config.TAG, "Thread interrupted: abort remaining retries!");
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    return;
                }

                // increase backoff exponentially
                backoff *= 2;
            }
        }

        String message = context.getString(R.string.server_register_error,
                MAX_ATTEMPTS);

        //Send Broadcast to Show message on screen
        displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
    }

    // Unregister this account/device pair within the server.
    void unregister(final Context context, final String regId) {

        Log.i(Config.TAG, "unregistering device (regId = " + regId + ")");

        String serverUrl = Config.YOUR_SERVER_URL + "/unregister";
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("regId", regId);

        try {
            post(serverUrl, params);
            GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregistered);
            displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // At this point the device is unregistered from GCM, but still
            // registered in the our server.
            // We could try to unregister again, but it is not necessary:
            // if the server tries to send a message to the device, it will get
            // a "NotRegistered" error message and should unregister the device.

            String message = context.getString(R.string.server_unregister_error,
                    e.getMessage());
            displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        }
    }

    // Issue a POST request to the server.
    private static void post(String endpoint, Map<String, String> params)
            throws IOException {

        URL url;
        try {

            url = new URL(endpoint);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid url: " + endpoint);
        }

        StringBuilder bodyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = params.entrySet().iterator();

        // constructs the POST body using the parameters
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
            bodyBuilder.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
                    .append(param.getValue());
            if (iterator.hasNext()) {
                bodyBuilder.append('&');
            }
        }

        String body = bodyBuilder.toString();

        Log.v(Config.TAG, "Posting '" + body + "' to " + url);

        byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {

            Log.e("URL", "> " + url);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
           conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");


            // post the request
            OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
            out.write(bytes);
            out.close();

            // handle the response
            int status = conn.getResponseCode();

            // If response is not success
            if (status != 200) {

                throw new IOException("Post failed with error code " + status);
            }
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }



    // Checking for all possible internet providers
    public boolean isConnectingToInternet(){

        ConnectivityManager connectivity =
                (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(
                        Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        return false;
    }

    // Notifies UI to display a message.
    void displayMessageOnScreen(Context context, String message) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Config.DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);



        // Send Broadcast to Broadcast receiver with message
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    }


    //Function to display simple Alert Dialog
    public void showAlertDialog(Context context, String title, String message,
                                Boolean status) {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();

        // Set Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle(title);

        // Set Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage(message);

        if(status != null)
            // Set alert dialog icon
            alertDialog.setIcon((status) ? R.drawable.success : R.drawable.fail);

        // Set OK Button
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        });

        // Show Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;

    public  void acquireWakeLock(Context context) {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release();

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        wakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "WakeLock");

        wakeLock.acquire();
    }

    public  void releaseWakeLock() {
        if (wakeLock != null) wakeLock.release(); wakeLock = null;
    }


}
```

Comment: 'BufferedReader bufferreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getEntity().getContent()));                            String msg="";
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = bufferreader.readLine()) != null) {
                        msg += line;
                    }
                    Log.i("msg=",""+msg);

Comment: Put the above code after out.close; and check the msg in logcat after running.

Comment: Failed to register on attempt 5:java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://local.test.com/gcmfile/register.php

Comment: local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80;LocalPort=45926(0)
04-30 15:20:57.535  13566-13600/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ [CDS]connect[local.test.com/192.99.166.230:80] tm:90
04-30 15:20:57.536  13566-13600/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi D/Posix﹕ [Posix_connect Debug]Process gcm.androidexample.com.ravi :80

04-30 15:20:58.275  13566-13600/gcm.androidexample.com.ravi I/System.out﹕ close [socket][/0.0.0.0:45926]

Comment: Search your logcat and just check what did have you gott for msg??

Comment: i read some one posting in stackoverflow its not possible to connect with local host. and one of my colleague also said same think.

Answer (score 3):

Error 403 in HTML is Forbidden, this means your server is not setup to accept xmlhttp or forum posts or you are using your service incorrectly.

Comment: how to overcome this problem,.